# Simple elisp bug

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've a little problem with the following code (it supposed to delete the file and kill the buffer):

```
(defun bk-deletes-file ()
  "Closes the buffer and deletes associated file."
  (interactive)
  (let (curFile curBuffer)
    (if (file-exists-p buffer-file-name)
        (progn
          (setq curFile buffer-file-name)
          (delete-file buffer-file-name))
      (setq curFile 1))
    (setq curBuffer (buffer-name))
    (kill-this-buffer)
    (if (stringp curFile)
        (message "I've deleted %s and buried its buffer %s"
                 (file-name-nondirectory curFile) curBuffer)
      (message "I've buried %s buffer" curBuffer)
      )))
```

It doesn't work: when I act on buffer-with-no-file it gives "if: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil", when I act on buffer-of-the-file it behaves as if it was buffer-with-no-file (that is it prints "I've buried %s buffer" - while it should print "I've deleted %s and buried its buffer %s")

Comment: As an aside, "burying" and "killing" are two distinct concepts. While the words share some semantics in real-world parlance, a buried Emacs buffer is never killed; it is just pushed to the back of the list of buffers.

Comment: @tripleee: Ok. I have had no need for "burying" for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is only one error and this is that the code cannot work on a buffer not associated with a file. In that case, `buffer-file-name` is `nil` and `file-exists-p` complains of not being passed a string.

Here is a version working (with a few improvements for readability and lisp good practices):

```
(defun bk-deletes-file ()
  "Kills the buffer and deletes associated file."
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-file (buffer-file-name))
        (current-buffer (buffer-name)))
    (when current-file
      (delete-file current-file))
    (kill-this-buffer)
    (if current-file
        (message "I've deleted %s and killed its buffer %s"
                 (file-name-nondirectory current-file) current-buffer)
      (message "I've killed %s buffer" current-buffer))))
```